# What is the editor used for writing RFC text files?

Tags: editor, rfc

I am just wondering how much effort is required to write a text file like that with page numbers, table of contents, headers, footers etc. Is there any editor or some thing like TeX that is used for writing the RFC documents?

Comment: I was looking for good rfc viewer. I found this to chrome: RFCRestyle. Hope help someone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [RFC 2223](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2223.txt):

> Most of the RFCs are processed by the RFC Editor with the unix
>   "nroff" program using a very simple set of the formatting commands
>   (or "requests") from the "ms" macro package (see the Appendix).

There is an RFC that details how they can be written using Microsoft Word: [RFC 3285: Using Microsoft Word to create Internet Drafts and RFCs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3285.txt) :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have written a couple of RFC-like documents in XML using the format described in [RFC2629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2629) and converting them using [xml2rfc](http://xml.resource.org/). There is also [a XSLT available](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2629xslt/rfc2629xslt.html) for doing the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Older RFCs were probably written with [nroff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nroff) or one of its relatives (troff, roff, groff).

Answer (score -1):

Write in some other format, like HTML/PDF/DOC and then export to text format. I guess that should be easier.

Comment: How do you "write in PDF"? :-)

Comment: Open Office :) http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Getting_Started/Exporting_to_PDF